# Magento 2 - extending validation/rules.js in custom module

Tags: magento2

Is there any way to extend `validation/rules.js` in custom module (not theme) with a new validation rule without overriding the original `rules.js`?

Answer (score 2):

This is the **best way** to add a new rule **without override the file rules.js** and use on LayoutProcessor.php or jsLayout.

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator'
    ],function ($,validator) {
    "use strict";
    return validator.addRule('validade-name-of-validation',
        function (value) {
            return /* your function */
        }, $.mage.__('Your error message.')
    );
});
```

Enjoy!